# jquery ajax form sended, but var_dump($_POST) empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

everyone, i got a very simple problem, but i am really confused... for un hour

in a php  page, i have the code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#date_avant").click(function(){
    $.post( "_corps_medecin_changedate.php", { name: 'test', id: '1' } );
    $("#consultations_jour").load("_corps_medecin_changedate.php");
  });
});
</script>
```

And in the page _corps_medecin_changedate.php, just at the beginning, i have the code:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
$date_debut = $_POST['name'];
?>
```

And i got msg:

```
array (size=0)
  empty
Notice: Undefined index: name
```

I checked the firebug, the parameters are correct in the post list, so i thinked it is sended correctly, but just canot receive in the action page.

```
Server info :   Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.4.4
```

And in local envirment.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your returned data from your `$.post` call is not automatically made available to your `.load()` call. They are two separate functions which means your call to `load` essentially send no POST data to the PHP script.

You can pass the post parameters as part of your call to `load`

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#date_avant").click(function(){
            $("#consultations_jour").load("_corps_medecin_changedate.php", { name: 'test', id: '1' });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle result of post request in callback function, like this:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#date_avant").click(function(){
    $.post( "_corps_medecin_changedate.php", { name: 'test', id: '1' }, 
         function(result) { $("#consultations_jour").html(result);} );
  });
});
</script>
```

In your code you make 2 different requests (first is in .post function, and second is in .load).

Answer (score 0):

that is because your are calling the `_corps_medecin_changedate.php` again right (`.load()`), after the post is made with no posted datas.. and you are  not using callbacks..

```
 $("#consultations_jour").load("_corps_medecin_changedate.php"); //here
```

**Since post is async**... the .load() function (which isn't inside a post's callback)  is called right after you call post and does not waits for it

i have no idea why are you loading the same php page again after post it made which i don't think is needed...but as an example ...you can use callback... to check the datas that you have posted

```
  $.post( "_corps_medecin_changedate.php", { name: 'test', id: '1' },function(data){
     alert('done');
  });

 //$("#consultations_jour").load("_corps_medecin_changedate.php");
```

try this and you should get the posted values in your PHP page.